# Looking for a simple macro/keyboard shortcut software

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

I'm looking for a simple software which would do this:

When I type in something like `dbs` and hit tab or enter, it will replace `dbs` with `$this->db->set()` in the program that I typed it in.

It needs to allow for multiple such shortcuts/templates. If there's a way to only put in these shortcuts in a specific program, or to dictate where the cursor should be put, that would be an added bonus.

The reason I want this, is because I'm too used to code templates in Netbeans, however in the latest version, they're broken for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: @Bob Windows XP ----

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) in [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). For example:

```
::dbs::$this->dbs->set()
```

> Unless the asterisk option is in effect, you must type an ending character after a hotstring's abbreviation to trigger it. Ending characters initially consist of the following: -()[]{}':;"/\,.?!`n `t (note that `n is Enter, `t is Tab, and there is a plain space between `n and `t). This set of characters can be changed by editing the following example, which sets the new ending characters for all hotstrings, not just the ones beneath it:
>
> ```
> #Hotstring EndChars -()[]{}:;'"/\,.?!`n `t
> ```

**The default `EndChars` includes tab and enter, but you may wish to remove some of the ending characters. The defaults appear to be chosen specifically for programmers.**

You can make it program specific with [`#IfWinActive`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm), for example:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
```

`#IfWinActive` affects all hotstrings defined after the directive, as described at the linked page. The `ahk_class` can be found with *AutoIt3 Window Spy*, a program included with AutoHotkey. You can also use window title, partial title, pid, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use AutoHotKey (http://www.autohotkey.com/) for this. You could listen for "d" "b" "s" "|" and replace it with "backspace" x 4, "$this->db->set()" etc. For example.